# cakephp use "OR" "AND" in find query

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am new in cakephp so i dont know i to how write this query in cakephp . at times now i have this query

```
  $count = $this->User->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array('User.mobileNo' => $mobileNo)));
```

this query is checking that if the mobile number in database is equal to the one the user has given .. i want to add another condition which is 
mobile number is equal to the one the user has given the mobile number and email is equal to the one the user has given the email for example

```
     $count = $this->User->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array('User.mobileNo' => $mobileNo))) And
   'conditions' => array('User.email' => $email)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only add to your conditions array:

```
$count = $this->User->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.mobileNo' => $mobileNo,
        'User.email' => $email
    )
));
```

There are many examples like this in the documentation [e.g.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions).

```
$conditions = array("Post.title" => "This is a post", "Post.author_id" => 1);
// Example usage with a model:
$this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```